# Check if value exists at specific key in a huge object full of associative arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, object, search, laravel

I have a huge object containing a a bunch of associative arrays all like this (output from PHP's `print_r()`) pulled from a MySQL table and returned:

```
Array (
    [id] => 70942
    [user_id] => 113
    [thread_id] => 3846
    [created_at] => 2013-12-15 20:50:47
    [updated_at] => 2014-02-05 15:18:12
)
```

There's a whole bunch of them, and I want to go through the object and check if there is at least one array in there where `user_id` matches some integer `x`. No idea how to do this...

I was thinking of using `array_search()` or `in_array()` I realize `array_search()` searches all keys not just a specified one, and this is making me feel super dumb...

Where to start? Object searching...

End goal is to increase query performance with eager loading. Right now I'm doing something like:

```
$threads = Thread::order_by('sticky', 'desc')->order_by('updated_at', 'desc')->take(25)->get();
if (Auth::check() && $thread->threadviews()->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('updated_at', '>=', $thread->updated_at)->count() == 0) { $unread = true; } else { $unread = false; }
```

which makes for a lot of queries, where I would really like to do this:

```
$threads = Thread::with('threadviews')->order_by('sticky', 'desc')->order_by('updated_at', 'desc')->take(25)->get();
```

then find out if there is a threadview that matches the user_id.

Comment: isn't this something to do in your MySQL query?

Comment: `array_search() searches all keys not just a specified one` **Nope** that function searches the array for value and if found returns the key.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran which would be a problem if `id` matched not `user_id` when that isn't really what we want.. right?

Comment: @kasperTaeymans yes, check the added info. Want to do eager loading here...